How to correctly implement of State Machine Pattern
I'm trying to implement State Machine Pattern for the state of a form, but I feel like it's not adding any convenience.
Context: user fills in a form on my webpage. User then saves the form. Upon saving, the form should get one of the following states:
public enum State
{
    [Description("NewForm")] // Initial state
    Draft = 0,

    [Description("Denied")] // Form was denied
    Afgekeurd = 1,

    [Description("Approved")] // Form was approved
    Afgerond = 2, 

    [Description("WaitForApprovalManager")] // Form needs manager approval
    WaitForApprovalManager = 3,

    [Description("WaitForApprovalTech")] // Form needs tech department approval
    WaitForApprovalTech = 4,

    [Description("WaitForApprovalFinance")] // Form needs finance department approval
    WaitForApprovalFinance = 5,
}

The state of a form is defined by business rules. For example:

If (form.totalpay < 500), Finance should approve the form state should be
If (form.totalpay >= 500), Finance and management should approve the form
If (form.totalpay >= 500 and form = tech): all departments should approve.

etc..
I made an attempt to make a state machine pattern, but I can't seem to understand why it's useful. So maybe I'm not doing it correctly. Tips are very welcome.
This is how I implemented the State Machine Pattern:
FormStateService:
public class FormStateService
{
    private FormState _currentState; // Current state of the form
    private Form _form; // Form that the user filled in
 
    public FormStateService(Form form)
    {
        _form = form;

        if (_currentState == null)
        {
            SetState(new DraftState()); // Set initial state to draft
        }
    }
 
    public void SetState(FormState state)
    {
        _currentState = state;
        _currentState.SetContext(_form);
    }
 
    public Form HandleStateTransition()
    {
        _currentState.HandleStateTransition(this);
        return _form;
    }
 
    public Status GetCurrentState()
    {
        return (State)_form.State;
    }
}

FormState:
public abstract class FormState
{
    protected Form _form;
 
    public void SetContext(Form form)
    {
        _form = form;
    }
 
    public abstract void HandleStateTransition(FormStateService stateMachine);
}

WaitForApprovalManagerState: each State has its own class like this with the business rules defined. For example this is what each stateclass looks like.
public override void HandleStateTransition(FormStateService stateMachine)
{
    if (_form.TotalReceipt >= 500) // Wait for managed to approve
    {
        _form.State = (int)Status.WaitForApprovalManagerState;
        stateMachine.SetState(new WaitForApprovalManagerState());
        return;
    }
 
    if (_form.TotalReceipt >= 500 && _form.ManagerApproved && _form.TechForm == true) // If manager has approved let tech approve
    {
        _form.State = (int)Status.WaitForApprovalTechState;
        stateMachine.SetState(new WaitForApprovalTechState());
        return;
    }
}


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I don't think the states are right. You wouldn't want them to represent a desired future state but the current state. So you would rather have states "Pending", "Approved" and "Denied". Your state object needs to persist which party approved already, so the next approval can trigger different state changes according to approval requirements.

Btw: the requirements are worded incorrectly. I guess it is supposed to say "... must approve". "Should" is a weak suggestion. So, approval wouldn't be mandatory.

To start with: Your approach is not efficient enough, because you use a fixed set of states. Each time you decide to modify enum State, you will have to modify a hell of code. You need a reasonable architecture totally agnostic to the concrete set of states. I developed some of such architectures and know that this is not so difficult. As a bonus, you can create not only the relationship over the set of states (that is, the subset of the Cartesian square of the set, а transition graph), but also define useful transition properties in your engine, for both valid and invalid state transitions.

My question for you: what made you think that you have to use this design pattern? This pattern is not good for all problems, it depends. In many cases, this is the main problem. I would understand that you clearly see the benefits of this pattern, but you don't understand how it is useful (and it is apparently extremely useful!) What is your motivation then? To please the authors of the pattern? To please your advisor or manager? Or to achieve your ultimate goals?

Please see my comment to the question: Your approach is not efficient enough. Below, you can find an almost fully functional generic state machine. You instantiate the generic class StateMachine<STATE> with the concrete enumeration type TestState (corresponding to your enumeration State). The enumeration members are collected using Reflection and converted to State instances, they populate the set of states. Then you create an instance of StateMachine<TestState> and populate the state machine transition graph with the arcs representing both valid and some (sic!) invalid transitions. Why invalid ones, too? Because this is a good place to place some delegate instances returning the string explaining why the transition is not allowed, please see the demo in Main. After the state machine is populated, you can perform the transitions. If a transition is valid, you can invoke some delegate instances created during the population. Basically, that's it. You have an abstraction used to configure a concrete state machine in any application field on Earth.
using Type = System.Type;
using BindingFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags;
using FieldInfo = System.Reflection.FieldInfo;
using StateSet = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<State>;

sealed class State {
    internal State(string name, object underlyingMember) {
        Name = name;
        UnderlyingMember = underlyingMember;
    } //State
    internal string Name { get; init; }
    internal object UnderlyingMember { get; init; }
} //class State

public delegate void StateTransitionAction<STATE>(STATE startingState, STATE endingState);
public delegate string InvalidStateTransitionAction<STATE>(STATE startingState, STATE endingState);

class StateGraphKey {
    internal StateGraphKey(State starting, State ending) {
        StartingState = starting; EndingState = ending;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() { // important!
        return StartingState.Name.GetHashCode()
            ^ EndingState.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object @object) { // important!
        if (@object == null) return false;
        if (@object is not StateGraphKey objectStateGraphKey) return false;
        return objectStateGraphKey.StartingState.Name == StartingState.Name
            && objectStateGraphKey.EndingState.Name == EndingState.Name;
    }
    internal State StartingState { get; init; }
    internal State EndingState { get; init; }
} //class StateGraphKey

class StateGraphValue<STATE> {
    internal StateGraphValue(StateTransitionAction<STATE> valid, InvalidStateTransitionAction<STATE> invalid) {
        ValidAction = valid; InvalidAction = invalid;
    }
    internal StateTransitionAction<STATE> ValidAction { get; init; }
    internal InvalidStateTransitionAction<STATE> InvalidAction { get; init; }
} //class StateGraphValue

abstract class StateTransition : StateGraphKey {
    internal StateTransition(State starting, State ending) :
        base(starting, ending) { }
    internal abstract bool IsValid { get; }
} //StateTransition

class ValidStateTransition : StateTransition {
    internal ValidStateTransition(State starting, State ending) :
        base(starting, ending) { }
    internal override bool IsValid { get { return true; } }
} //class ValidStateTransition

class InvalidStateTransition : StateTransition {
    internal InvalidStateTransition(State starting, State ending) :
        base(starting, ending) { }
    internal override bool IsValid { get { return false; } }
} //class ValidStateTransition

public class StateMachine<STATE> {

    public StateMachine(STATE initialState = default(STATE)) {
        Type type = typeof(STATE);
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var field in fields) {
            State state = new State(field.Name, field.GetValue(null));
            stateSet.Add(state);
            if (initialState.ToString() == field.Name)
                CurrentState = (STATE)state.UnderlyingMember;
        } //loop
    } //StateMachine
    public STATE CurrentState { get; private set; }
    static State CreateState(STATE value) => new State(value.ToString(), value);
    bool IsValid(StateGraphValue<STATE> value) => value.ValidAction != null;
    public void AddValidStateTransition(STATE startingState, STATE endingState, StateTransitionAction<STATE> action) {
        StateGraphKey key = new(CreateState(startingState), CreateState(endingState));
        if (stateGraph.TryGetValue(key, out StateGraphValue<STATE> value))
            return; //SA???
        stateGraph.Add(key, new StateGraphValue<STATE>(action, null));
    } //AddValidStateTransition
    public void AddInvalidStateTransition(STATE startingState, STATE endingState, InvalidStateTransitionAction<STATE> action) {
        StateGraphKey key = new(CreateState(startingState), CreateState(endingState));
        if (stateGraph.TryGetValue(key, out StateGraphValue<STATE> value))
            return; //SA???
        stateGraph.Add(key, new StateGraphValue<STATE>(null, action));
    } //AddInvalidStateTransition
    public string IsTransitionValid(STATE startingState, STATE endingState) {
        State starting = CreateState(startingState);
        State ending = CreateState(endingState);
        StateGraphKey key = new(starting, ending);
        bool found = stateGraph.TryGetValue(key, out StateGraphValue<STATE> value);
        if (found && !IsValid(value) && value.InvalidAction != null) {
            return value.InvalidAction(startingState, endingState);
        }
        return null;
    } //IsTransitionValid
    public bool TryTransitionTo(STATE state, out string invalidTransitionReason) {
        invalidTransitionReason = null;
        State starting = CreateState(CurrentState);
        State ending = CreateState(state);
        StateGraphKey key = new(starting, ending);
        bool found = stateGraph.TryGetValue(key, out StateGraphValue<STATE> value);
        if (IsValid(value))
            value.ValidAction(CurrentState, state);
        else
            value.InvalidAction(CurrentState, state);
        CurrentState = state;
        return found;
    } //TryTransitionTo
    public void PerformTransitionIndirect(STATE startingState, STATE endingState) {
        //SA??? complicated algorithm of graph search
    } //PerformTransition
    StateSet stateSet = new();
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<StateGraphKey, StateGraphValue<STATE>> stateGraph = new();
} //class StateMachine

Demo:
using Console = System.Console;

enum TestState { Draft, Denied, Approved, WaitForApprovalManager, WaitForApprovalTechnical, WaitForApprovalFinance, }

class Test {
    static void Main() {
        var stateMachine = new StateMachine<TestState>();
        stateMachine.AddValidStateTransition(TestState.Draft, TestState.WaitForApprovalManager, (starting, ending) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to get approval from manager");
        });
        stateMachine.AddValidStateTransition(TestState.Draft, TestState.WaitForApprovalTechnical, (starting, ending) => { });
        stateMachine.AddValidStateTransition(TestState.Draft, TestState.WaitForApprovalFinance, (starting, ending) => { });
        stateMachine.AddInvalidStateTransition(TestState.Denied, TestState.WaitForApprovalManager, (starting, ending) =>
            $"{TestState.Denied} to {TestState.WaitForApprovalManager}? Come on! It is already denied, don't wait!");
        Console.WriteLine(stateMachine.IsTransitionValid(TestState.Draft, TestState.WaitForApprovalManager));
        Console.WriteLine(stateMachine.IsTransitionValid(TestState.Denied, TestState.WaitForApprovalManager));
        Console.WriteLine(stateMachine.CurrentState);
        stateMachine.TryTransitionTo(TestState.WaitForApprovalManager);
        Console.WriteLine(stateMachine.CurrentState);
    } //Main
} //class Test

This code can also give you an idea of why state machines can be very useful. Look at the not-yet-implemented method PerformTransitionIndirect. You can use some not-so-sophisticated graph algorithm to search valid paths through several states automatically. But even without that method, you already can do a lot: you can directly perform actions on a state machine and examine the state machine graph to validate the transitions between any two states. You can get an explanation of why a transition is invalid.
You can use absolutely any enumeration type to define a set of states, which is supposed to be static, as the state machine pattern assumes. Strictly speaking, any type could serve the purpose, not only enumeration. Only one enumeration feature is used: the type should have several public static members. The names of these members are used and the names of states.
Note: I created this code from scratch in much less than an hour, as everything was in my head. The code is published in an open-source GitHub repository. I just got a few new ideas I wanted to implement. The prototype is already published in my article on enumeration types and their problems.
The present version of the code is self-contained and can be build without any dependencies.
